# Start thread returns System.InvalidOperationException: The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, multithreading

I add a dashboard `devexpress` that run a stored procedure and it takes a long time. So I created a simple thread in my application in `form_load`

```
public void LoadDashboard()
{
    using (Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Resource.Dashboard.MaterialDashboard1)))
    {
         s.Position = 0;
         dashboardViewer1.LoadDashboard(s);
    }
}

private void frmMaterialDashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread newth=new Thread(LoadDashboard);
    newth.Start();

    int UserId = int.Parse(Configuration.AccountDetail.UserId.ToString());
    lblUserName.Caption = _userRepository.Get().Where(i => i.Id == UserId).First().FullName;

    alertControl1.Show(this, "Welcome","Welcome to SPMS Mr."+_userRepository.FindById(Configuration.AccountDetail.UserId).First().FullName +"\n Server time:"+DateTime.Now);
}
```

But when I run my application I get this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'DevExpress.DashboardCommon.DashboardInternalException' occurred in DevExpress.Dashboard.v15.2.Win.dll
>
> Additional information: Internal error. Please contact the application vendor or your system administrator and provide the following information.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler..ctor()
>   at DevExpress.DashboardWin.Native.WinDashboardService.RequestCustomizationServices(RequestCustomizationServicesEventArgs e)
>   at DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Service.DashboardService.DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Service.IDashboardServiceAdminHandlers.OnRequestCustomizationServices(Object sender, RequestCustomizationServicesEventArgs e)
>   at DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Server.DashboardSession.CreateDataLoaderParameters(ReloadDataArgs args)
>   at DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Server.DashboardSession.CreateDataLoader(ReloadDataArgs args)
>   at DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Server.DashboardSession.LoadData(IEnumerable`1 dataSourceComponentNames, ReloadDataArgs args)
>
>   at DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Server.DashboardSession.ReloadData(IEnumerable`1 dataSourceComponentNames, ReloadDataArgs args)
>   at DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Server.DashboardSession.Initialize(DashboardSessionState state, Boolean isDesignMode)
>   at DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Service.DashboardServiceOperation`1.Execute(DashboardServiceResult result)

**Updated**

I change my code like this, it works without any error and the data is shown but without any async operation and I have to wait to load data

```
public async Task<Stream> LoadDashboard()
{
    Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Resource.Dashboard));
    s.Position = 0;
    return s;
}

private async void frmMaterialDashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream dashboardData = await LoadDashboard();
    dashboardViewer1.LoadDashboard(dashboardData);

    int UserId = int.Parse(Configuration.AccountDetail.UserId.ToString());
    lblUserName.Caption = _userRepository.Get().Where(i => i.Id == UserId).First().FullName;
    alertControl1.Show(this, "Welcome","Welcome to SPMS Mr."+_userRepository.FindById(Configuration.AccountDetail.UserId).First().FullName +"\n Server time:"+DateTime.Now);
}
```

Comment: Gotcha - nvrmind... Thanks for updated info.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger i just have this thread in my application

Comment: Yeah what little I know about that namespace looks like a UI "thing" (control, whatever), which you're going to have problems with if you run on a separate thread. Have you tried running it on the UI thread for fun & adventure?

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger no i don't

Comment: From the customer service website: In most cases, the problem is caused by incorrect use of background threads in the application. Our controls like standard ones are not thread safe. This means that they cannot be accessed from another thread rather than a thread in which they were created. Any object cannot be accessed from other threads. A solution to this problem is described in the following MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger so you mean i can't do this with thread !?What is the solution ?

Comment: Check out the MSDN article link at the end of my last comment - it includes ways to instantiate the dashboard in a threadsafe manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without full context of the problem I can't give you an exact solution, but overall, you cannot access UI elements from another thread. That means you need to do all request and computation on another thread, and then update UI elements on UI thread. Consider such simplified solution that does not explicitly start a new thread:

```
// event on UI thread    
private async void frmMaterialDashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dashboardData = await LoadDashboardDataFromDatabaseAsync();
    dashboardViewer1.Load(dashboardData);
}

public async Task<DashboardData> LoadDashboardDataFromDatabaseAsync()
{
    string query = "...";
    var queryResult = await db.ExucuteQueryAsync(query).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return ConvertQueryRequltToDashboardData(queryResult);
}
```

Comment: I changed my code and i implemented your solution ,my code is running without any error ,but the loading is remains i think the async function is not called async

Comment: if you have a synchronous database call, you should wrap it into a task: `var queryResult = await Task.Run(() => db.Execute(query)).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: I think i should add await  keyword to my loaddata function ,am i right ?

Comment: I suggest you to post your modified code to as an update to your question

Comment: I added it to end of my question

Comment: I asked the problem in another question could you please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536163/async-memorystream-approach-in-c-sharp-to-get-data-async