# async Memorystream approach in c# to get data async

Tags: c#, asynchronous

My dashboard needs too much time to get data from database so I have to use `async` approach to handle this problem here is my code :

```
public async Task < Stream > LoadDashboard() {
   Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Resource.Dashboard));
   s.Position = 0;
   return s;
}

private async void frmMaterialDashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Stream dashboardData = await LoadDashboard();
   dashboardViewer1.LoadDashboard(dashboardData);

  //show UI components for user interact
}
```

My code doesn't work and I have to wait for data to come from the database. Should I add anything else ?

This part of code takes long time to load data

```
 Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Resource.Dashboard));
 s.Position = 0;
```

I want to execute this part async. When my form is loaded I want to call `LoadDashboard` as a background task to get the data from database ,and the main thread show my user interface form .

The component link that I am using :

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Dashboard/CustomDocument113927

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Side note: `MemoryStream` has no asynchronous functionality... Very unclear what you expect from marking completely synchronous LoadDashboard function with `async`.

Comment: Your code queries Database in synchronous mode. Use FirstAsync instead. And Memory stream does nothing asynchronous

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just want to load data async in LoadDashboard function ,and allow my user to interact with my ui (menus)

Comment: But what part of this code do you think could be executed asynchronously? Note: "asynchronous" is not the same as "on another thread". They are related, but different and distinct, topics.

Comment: @MarcGravell this part of code read an xml file .in the xml file i call and store procedure ,the store procedure is executed on a huge amount of data so it takes long time so i have to execute this part async new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Resource.Dashboard));

Comment: How long time it takes for LoadDashBoard to finish?

Comment: @Artiom it takes 5 min

Comment: @EhsanAkbar now we're talking; database access is a good thing to async, as long as you're *actually using the async API to do it*; then you can just `await` the DB code.

Comment: Mayble this can help :https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Dashboard/CustomDocument113927

Comment: `My dashboard needs too much time to get data from database so I have to use async approach` - but `async` doesn't make anything faster.

Comment: @StephenCleary i just one to use a background thread to get my data from database ,and main thread shows the UI to my user for interacting

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like you have no actual async work you can do, you are reading a resource in to a memory stream. Putting the `async` keyword on somthing does nothing by itself, the function still runs just like it used to. If you want the work to happen in the background you have to tell it to work in the background by using a new thread.

```
//Get rid of this async stuff here.
public Stream LoadDashboard()
{

    Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Resource.Dashboard));
    s.Position = 0;
    return s;

}

private async  void frmMaterialDashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Start LoadDashboad in a background thread and await it.
    Stream dashboardData = await Task.Run(() => LoadDashboard());
    dashboardViewer1.LoadDashboard(dashboardData);

    //show UI components for user interact
}
```

---

Another option is to not copy the string to a memory stream and instead get the stream directly

```
private void frmMaterialDashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var dashboardStream = Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("Dashboard"))
    {
        dashboardViewer1.LoadDashboard(dashboardStream);
    }

    //show UI components for user interact
}
```

I got rid of the async because DashboadViewer does not provide a way to call LoadDashboard from the background to the best of my knowledge. You will have to wait till it finishes loading or figure out how to get smaller data.

Comment: I put a break point after this line in my code dashboardViewer1.LoadDashboard(dashboardData); and never called and executed why ?.

Comment: Because `LoadDashboard` is still working, you likely have a huge amount of data if your first method took a long time. You likely need to rethink how you are using the dashboard, perhaps there is a way to reduce the amount of data you are passing it.

Comment: Async execution doesn't mean it will be executed at once. It means your main thread won't be blocked and will continue execution once loading is finished

Comment: @EhsanAkbar try my updated version, you don't need a MemoryStream at all, you can just use a StringReader

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you dear friend your updated doesn't need any async function ?

Comment: @your update has a convert error :string to stream convert

Comment: What is the datatype of `Resource.Dashboard`? And I removed the update, did not realize `StringReader` did not return a class derived from `Stream`

Comment: Dear friend i get this error :An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in DevExpress.Dashboard.v15.2.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
I changed your code like this because it has a compile error using (var dashboardStream = Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(Resource.Dashboard))
Additional information: Value cannot be null.